# How to implement hibernate versioning on specific columns?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have implemented Hibernate versioning on a table and the version column updates on any updates on the table.

My requirement is to implement the versioning capability on specific column

```
create table test
(
id number primary key,
name varchar,
city varchar,
version number
)
```

In current implemented version, column increments on change of name or city, however I want version to increment only on change of name.

Answer (score 0):

These are Optimistic Lock Types:

```
public enum OptimisticLockType {
    /**
     * Perform no optimistic locking.
     */
    NONE,
    /**
     * Perform optimistic locking using a dedicated version column.
     *
     * @see javax.persistence.Version
     */
    VERSION,
    /**
     * Perform optimistic locking based on *dirty* fields as part of an expanded WHERE clause restriction for the
     * UPDATE/DELETE SQL statement.
     */
    DIRTY,
    /**
     * Perform optimistic locking based on *all* fields as part of an expanded WHERE clause restriction for the
     * UPDATE/DELETE SQL statement.
     */
    ALL
}
```

So there is no specific columns lock, but you can implements your own. As you know when you have `@Version` Optimistic Lock the query would be something like this:

```
UPDATE TEST SET NAME = ?, CITY = ? WHERE ID = ? AND VERSION = ?
```

This query will insure that the version of your entity should be same as the version that you read. So now you want just check the version changes on `name` column. So you need to execute a query like this:

```
UPDATE TEST SET NAME = ?, CITY = ? WHERE ID = ? AND NAME = ?
```

So you just check `name` **old value** to be the value which you read before. And also in this solution you don't need version and you can omit that from your entity. Also don't forget to implement this logic for `DELETE` query.